# Handling unassigned (null) values of categorical features in regression (machine learning)?

Tags: null, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, categorical-data

I want to do linear regression analysis. I have multiple features. Some features has unassigned (null) values for some items in data. For ordinal features (for example 'year' or 'number of rooms') I can use mean value imputation and replace all nulls by mean value of data. But what to do with categorical features (for example color or district)?
To be more clear, I provide example: [image]

There are several features of categorical type:

```
Color, material, security, type, district
```

How to impute null values in categorical features without too much complex imputation methods? I was adviced to just keep "Null" itself as a separate data variant. So, for example in 'District' column "Null" is going to be new 'district'. Is it rational to use such simple imputation for all that kind of categorical features or may be more or less simple and better imputation method exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use NULL as a new level in categorical variables. If you only need simple imputation methods for categorical variables, you can also try to impute  with the most frequent level(value) of that variable or some simple rules that are reasonable for this dataset.